# Запрос cURL: как получить ответ от сервера?

Tags: curl, php

Привет всем, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Выполняю POST запрос  на сервак с помощью cURL (из программы)

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://127.0.0.1/arena.php');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $time);
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Запрос идет к скрипту arena.php, там элементарное содержание.

arena.php (на сайте)

```
<?php
$time = $_POST['time'];
echo "$time";
?>
```

Как получить  это самое echo  в программе?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в переменной $data и находится  резудьтат вывода  echo "$time";

Comment: таки да! :)